# Selenium Python options click

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, helper

I want help in a little thing,
Look this:

[image]

I want to press the `option` named **Boleto Bancario**, but look the html

[image]

Than how I will press the second option with selenium PYTHON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check the snippet.

1. You can select by `value`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('url')
sct = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('idFormaPagamento'))

sct.select_by_value('813640')
```

2. You can select by `index`

```
sct.select_by_index('1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the value in any dropdown by three different ways:

```
select_by_value()
select_by_index()
select_by_visible_text()
```

So you may simply go and choose the option like this:

```
select_by_value('813640')
select_by_index('1')
select_by_visible_text('Boleto Bancario')
```

Hope this works for you.